# set the permissions on all the files and folders within a directory (CentOS 7.0 )

Tags: linux, centos7, user-permissions, chmod, setfacl

I kind of new to Linux/Centos world, is there any way to set the permissions on all the files and folders within a directory. I know chmod 777 will set permissions on the directory, but if it already has contents, I need to know how to set that too. In windows, you propagate the permission down, must be a way to do that in Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `-R, --recursive` flag

[Link to the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod#:%7E:text=R%2C%20%2D%2D-,recursive,-change%20files%20and)

```
OPTIONS

<...omitted for brevity...>

       -R, --recursive
              change files and directories recursively
```

Comment: Mandatory comment that `chmod 777` is garbage and should never be performed, much less so with `--recursive` and even less so when you don't know `--recursive` without asking on StackOverflow.